# Multiple Python telnet write and read commands without timer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer, telnet, telnetlib

```
while True:
    command = raw_input("=> ")
    if command == 'Exit':
        tn.write(command + "\r\n")
        time.sleep(1)
        tn.close()
        break
tn.write(command + "\r\n")
time.sleep(2)
print tn.read_very_eager()
```

I've established a connection to the Telnet and I'm passing through basic commands. I want to avoid a 1 or 2 second timer between each write command because I don't want 30 write commands to take up to a minute. If I remove 'time.sleep,' I can't read the output in time for the next command. Can anyone help?

Comment: I ended up using tn.expect and it appears to have reduced my script's run time considerably.